# Drag and Drop Jquery upload to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, upload, drag-and-drop

I have seen many topics about this problem but none of them got a legit answer or a including PHP file.

I want to make a drag & drop saving tool. The problem is that my files are not getting uploaded to my ftp folder.

I got the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="drop_zone">
  <p>Drop Here</p>
</div>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="yourregularuploadformId">
       <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');    
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

etc.... dropping part

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    files = evt.dataTransfer.files; 
    uploadFile(files);
```

etc... getting file to my method

```
function uploadFile(droppedFiles){
    // add your files to the regular upload form
   var uploadFormData = new FormData($("#yourregularuploadformId")[0]); 
    if(droppedFiles.length > 0) { // checks if any files were dropped
        for(f = 0; f < droppedFiles.length; f++) { // for-loop for each file dropped
            uploadFormData.append("files[]",droppedFiles[f]);  // adding every file to the form so you could upload multiple files
        }
    }
 // the final ajax call
    alert(uploadFormData);
       $.ajax({
        url : "php/uploadFile.php", // use your target
        type : "POST",
        data : uploadFormData,
        cache : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success : function(ret) {
                 alert(ret);
        }
       });
  }
```

Got the above code from another topic. (alert(uploadFormData); -> gives me a Formdata aboject)

**PHP:**

```
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "ftp/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Can't make it work :<

The message i get from the callback function in my JS is:

Undefined index: file

Comment: See here then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206011/how-can-i-move-a-file-to-another-folder-using-php

Comment: Have you looked at the request payload in your browser?  What does the name property of each file multipart boundary look like?  Your PHP code is looking for a file with a "name" value of "file".  I don't see how this is correct, based on your javascript.

Comment: I'm sorry Ray, i have no clue what you mean by "looked at the request payload in your browser" :( how do you do that? :)

Comment: Have a look at the network tab in Chrome dev tools, or in Firebug, for example.

Comment: I see !! thanx :) this is my output:

------WebKitFormBoundarykTwWycDebBDlvAmN
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code needs to iterate over all of the files in the request.  Based on your javascript, your PHP code should look something like this:

```
foreach ($_FILES["files"] as $file) {
    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $target);
}
```

The `$target` variable must point at the local destination for your file.  See the PHP manual for more details.

Comment: That was it ! :) so simple when you think about it :) Thank you very much ! Small thing if you have time left: how do i give every file i upload a unique name - like md5 encryption :)

Comment: If you want a unique ID for each file, you can easily do this server-side by generating a [`uniqid` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).